# Can I remove the "videos" tab from my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I don't have any videos on my page and I don't plan to change this anytime soon. Is there any way to remove the link?

In *Manage Tabs » Add or remove tabs* I can only add apps but not remove or disable the Videos tab.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a way of doing this directly.  However, you can use the plugin from [Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/).

This enables you to turn off and/or hide several "features" of the Facebook page like this.

It isn't available for all browsers on all operating systems but it covers most combinations.

Comment: How exactly would social fixer help? I'm talking about disabling it for a page I manage, i.e. so others don't see a useless tab...

Comment: I read your question as meaning on the page as you viewed it.